# Angular 5 in safepipe get error - Required a safe ResourceURL, got a HTML

Tags: angular, angular5

In Angular 5, I want to show a map in `iFrame`. I used safepipe, however, receives error in console

> Required a safe ResourceURL, got a HTML

Here is the code is my `.ts` file:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class XXXComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

this.mapURL = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyDdWRYxwcpnrJWXbsR4fmP3HwvsFlCMYPk&q=Ylistörmä+1,+02210+Espoo,+Finland&attribution_source=Google+Maps+Embed+API";
this.urlsafe = this.createSafeMap(this.mapURL);

createSafeMap(url){
   return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(url);
}
```

In the `.html` file, I did the following to show the map in iframe:

```html
<iframe [src]="urlsafe | safe: 'html'"></iframe>
```

Below is the content of `safe.pipe.ts`:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    
@Pipe({
   name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
    
   constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
     
   public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
      switch (type) {
         case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
         case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
         case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
         case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
         case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
         default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @yurzui receives `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'SafeValue%20must%20use%20%5Bproperty%5D' `

Comment: @yurzui perfect. Please put this as answer so that I can vote it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use url safely you simply need to write `safe` pipe with `resourceUrl` parameter and throw away your `urlsafe` wrapper:

```
[src]="mapURL | safe: 'resourceUrl'"
```

Answer (score 0):

In .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  templateUrl: './fileName.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fileName.component.scss']
})

export class FileName implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  url: string = "www.example.com";
  urlSafe: SafeResourceUrl;

  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.urlSafe= this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
  }

}
```

fot .html File

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" [src]="urlSafe"></iframe>
```

This setup worked for me like a champ. Enjoy.